# Migrate DocuSign records from one Salesforce organization to another Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am using Docusign in my Salesforce Org and we are migrating to new org due to some business purposes and now we would like to migrate Docusign documents and templates to new org. Is it possible? What are the considerations and issues that we could face?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this as your old ref ids will not line up with your new org.

If your envelopes are still on the DocuSign side then you can do a mass push via envelope publish - but the as I said the IDs won't line up, so it would just be like a repo.

To do this, in the DocuSign side under Settings > Connect > Envelope Publish
You get a list of all of your envelopeIds, then feed it into Connect telling it to write back attachments
Connect pushes the entire envelope list including docs to your salesforce org --but where it goes in Salesforce I'm not certain

It is currently not possible to automatically copy or transfer the DocuSign for Salesforce settings or Envelope Configurations from one Salesforce environment to another. This means that you’ll need to install and configure DocuSign for Salesforce and recreate the Envelope Configurations in each Salesforce instance.